# wpdb get_results выводит только первую строку в таблице

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Выводит только первую строку в таблице, как сделать, что-бы выводилось вся таблица?

```
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'cities';
    $spisok = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_cities ORDER BY id ASC", ARRAY_A);

        foreach ($spisok as $spiski) {
            $name = $spiski[name]; $id = $spiski[id]; $description = $spiski[description];
            return array(
                array(
                    'ex_id' => $id, 
                    'ex_name' => $name, 
                    'ex_description' => $description,
                ),
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так Вы же возвращаете результат после первой итерации.

```
$cities = [];
foreach ($spisok as $spiski) {
            $name = $spiski[name]; $id = $spiski[id]; $description = $spiski[description];

                $cities[] = array(
                    'ex_id' => $id, 
                    'ex_name' => $name, 
                    'ex_description' => $description,
                );

        }
return $cities;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает.